# Wordpress file upload media_handle_upload fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a PHP script to process files sent to it via POST.

On the frontend js script, I create a Formdata object, and append images to it...like:

```
formdata.append('image0', image0);
formdata.append('image1', image1);
```

etc

This is my PHP code, the code is in the wordpress root directory

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");


require_once('wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once('wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once('wp-admin/includes/media.php' );



$id_array = array();

$c = 0;

foreach ($_FILES as $file) {

$id_array[] = media_handle_upload('image' . $c, 0);
$c++;
}


echo implode(',', $id_array);
```

However when I run this code, I get the following error:

Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in **/home/website/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php** on line **16**

Am i missing to include additional files in the script? I used the documentation on wordpress and it said:

These files need to be included as dependencies when on the front end.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: `__()` is a WordPress native function for translation support. Try any of these [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/install-fails-with-fatal-error-undefined-function-_)

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the native Wordpress functions, such as __() wp-config.php needs to be included additionally.

Adding wp-config.php solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing same issue.
Adding this in functions.php will fix the error.
Some time it will show as "http error"

```
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'raj_change_graphic_library' );
function raj_change_graphic_library($array) {
 return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick' );
}
```